# Why won't my CSS link?

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I can't seem to get my CSS to link to my page. I've tried multiple fixed already on the website and I've had a few people look at is but for some reason it just wont work. I've tried putting it in the Web-inf, and multiple difference ways in which too link the CSS.

JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-default">Hello</div>
<p>${topAlbums.size() }</p>
<c:forEach items="${topAlbums}" var="album">
     <p>${album}</p>
</c:forEach>
    </body>
        </html>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring Web App</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebapp">    </context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="de.umass"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwNDZ.png

Files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOCzN.png

UPDATE:

Got this working, it was something in my dispatcher servlet blocking all CSS files. Thanks for all the help people :)

Comment: The path is correct. Not sure about the rest, how should I check. Sorry, I'm only a beginner.

Comment: Yep, I get a 404 when I try and reach it from the browser, however I've tried mutiple paths and none seem to work.

Comment: On  localserver, I just went into my eclipse and run the bootstrap file directly on the server and still get a 404. So the path is definitely correct, it just can't seem to access it.

Comment: Windows. Thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: Doesn't say anything about permissions when I right click it on system explorer and eclipse

Comment: Nope, there is a properties option but no security option

Comment: Windows 8. I'd be happy to teamviewer if you want to try yourself :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying. I'll ask the question again in the morning with different tags.